# DNX Core 5.0 library to target any platform. No System.Random class. Workarounds or options?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dnx, .net-core

I am trying out the Visual Studio 2015 RC project template for creating a class library

> that can target any platform

says Visual Studio.

A new project has 2 references: DNX 4.5.1 and DNX Core 5.0. It appears that `System.Random` is not available in DNX Core 5.0. (The same is true for the .NET Core 5.0 Console project template.)

For .NET Core libraries/apps, what options are there for generating random numbers?

---

To truly *target any platform*, I guess one could implement a pseudorandom number generator, or wait until a DNX Core-compatible reference is available, that has someone else implement a PRNG. Microsoft could be that someone by the time 2015 is no longer "RC".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's included in [System.Runtime.Extensions package](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=random). Add it to dependencies and run `dnu restore` if you are building from the command line. Then it should build.

Comment: I didn't run `dnu restore` but the project builds. You probably were using the NuGet command line? I used the GUI.

Comment: @T.Webster Not if you build from Visual Studio I guess.

Comment: forgive a basic question, since outside of work, I haven't had much time to explore distributing a .NET Core app that targets *any* platform. Have you yet built, e.g. some .NET Core Console app on Windows, and had it run on Windows and Linux (and Android)? I haven't read *all* the documentation yet, but this isn't as simple as copying some universal executable on other platforms is it? To run on non-Windows OS requires installing  some .NET Core runtime first, or not? I can post a new question, let me know.

Comment: @T.Webster You have to install the runtime on other operating systems too.

Answer (score 3):

Look at Microsoft's [`System.Random` source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,bb77e610694e64ca)

See if a copy & paste will compile.

If you don't intend to generate lots of instances of PRNGs, then `DateTime.Now.Ticks` is supported by DNX 5.0 and could be used as the seed.